# what is the use of max_server_pool_size configuration for supertokens

Tags: identity, supertokens

I trying to setup supertoken for my project and looking at the config.yaml file for supertoken-postgres docker image.
One thing I am curious about what is the purpose of max_server_pool_size configuration and in what scenarios I would change it to a higher or lower value then the default 10.
If I have a docker container with 1 vCPU and 2 GB RAM can I set it to 20.